# Filter resource table by registered user id or current user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I'm starting with laravel/filamentphp in version 10 and I want to automatically filter the table of a resource so that the current user looks only at its records that I capture.

I have the “user” model related to the “sale” model through the user id, that is, in the “sale” migration table I have:

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users')->cascadeOnDelete();
```

and in the main index (table) of the “sale” resource the user ID appears in the corresponding record that was captured.

But I can't or rather I don't know how to make a query to filter by user and their id automatically.

I hope you can guide me and give me support.thank you

Filter resource table by registered user id or current user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a relationship between User and Sale, like in User Model add this:

```
public function sales()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Sale::class);
}
```

then in controller function you can get the values like

```
public function userSales(){
   $user = Auth::user();
   $sales = $user->sales;
   // .... remaining logic
}
```

If you want to retrieve data without defining relationship you can get through this:

```
public function userSales(){
   $user = Auth::id;
   $sales = Sale::where('user_id', $user)->get();
   // .... remaining logic
}
```